# Game piece movement optimization; given certain rules, find the minimum number of moves

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, chess

Alright, so this is a fun one. I'm trying to code the movement of a piece in Japanese chess (also called shogi), specifically the silver general. The rules of the piece's movement are as such:

For position (x,y), the piece can move to either (x-1,y+1), (x,y+1), (x+1,y+1), (x-1,y-1), or (x+1,y-1). In other words, the piece can move to any of the spaces directly diagonal to it or to the space directly above it, but cannot move directly left, right, or down.

So I'm defining a function that takes the starting position (sx,sy) and the final position (gx,gy) as arguments and finds the quickest path between the two. Things seem to work for the case in which the starting and ending coordinates lie together on a horizontal or vertical line, but things start to fall apart after that. I don't know if I'm missing a condition, or if there's a better way to do this, but the function needs to work with the given arguments. Does anybody have any advice that might point me in the right direction? My code is as follows:

```
def minSteps(sx,sy,gx,gy):
    count = 0
    while [sx,sy] != [gx,gy]:
        if (gy != sy and gx == sx):
            if gy > sy:
                sx = sx
                sy += 1
                count += 1
            else:
                sx += 1
                sy -= 1
                count += 1
        elif (gy == sy and gx != sx):
            if gx > sx:
                sx += 1
                sy += 1
                count += 1
            else:
                sx -= 1
                sy += 1
            count += 1
        elif (gy != sy and gx != sx):
            if gy > sy:
                if gx > sx:
                    sx += 1
                    sy += 1
                    count += 1
                else:
                    sx -= 1
                    sy += 1
                    count += 1
            if gy < sy:
                if gx > sx:
                    sx += 1
                    sy -= 1
                    count += 1
                else:
                    sx -= 1
                    sy -= 1
                    count += 1
    return count
```

---

---

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try the [A* Search Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) which can search the problem space for the minimum number of steps.  Given the limited move options, the algorithm may need to be tweaked to specialise for the Shogi-limited movements.

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the space is "infinite". So, I'm naming the different moves this way:

- A = (x+1,y+1)
- B = (x+1,y-1)
- C = (x-1,y-1)
- D = (x-1,y+1)
- E = (x,y+1)

Since the order of these moves doesn't matter, instead of looking for a path, I prefer to count how many As, how many Bs, etc.

If we only consider A, B, C and D moves, then, we would have a grid seen in diagonal.
Points that are not part of this grid can be connected to the grid using an E move.

So, step 1: find x and y relative to the starting point:

```
x = gx-sx;
y = gy-sy;
```

Step 2: all counters to zero:

```
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
d = 0;
e = 0;
```

Step 3: if the point is not in "the grid", move it to the grid, using an E move:

```
if ((x&1) ^ (y&1)) {e=1; y--;}
```

Step 4: since it is easier for me to operate in positive numbers domain, numbers are mirrored in case of negative:

```
if (x<0) {hor=1; x=-x;}
else hor=0;
if (y<0) {ver=1; y=-y;}
else ver=0;
```

Step 5: Once all numbers are positive, I found either B and A counters, or D and A counters:

```
if (x>y) {b=(x-y)/2; a=y+b;}
else {d=(y-x)/2; a=x+d;}
```

Step 6: If numbers were mirrored, swap the counters accordingly (right becomes left, up becomes down):

```
if (hor) {hor=a; a=d; d=hor; c=b; b=0;}
if (ver) {ver=a; a=b; b=ver; ver=c; c=d; d=ver;}
```

...and that's it. Solution is in a,b,c,d,e counters. If you really need a path, you can derive it from the move counters.

Final note: there are multiple solutions in counters, because you can convert: A + D = 2 E